# ComboBox bug in IE11 - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-11

Does anybody know about a jQuery-Mobile bug in IE11 according to the combobox / select-Tag?

Small snippet to demonstrate:

```
<select name="language" id="cboLanguage">
    <option value="1">1 test</option>
    <option value="2">11 test</option>
    <option value="3">11test</option>
    <option value="4">something else</option>
</select>
```

Normally it is possible with select-Tab to focus, navigate with arrow keys or press letters and the correct/fullfilling option is automatically displayed.
This works with Firefox and IE the same without using jQuery-Mobile (e.g. typing '11t' automatically shows '11test' as value).

If I include the jQuery-Mobile and jQuery Script, the scenario is still working in Firefox but not in IE11. After typing one letter, the next value beginning with this letter is shown and the combobox loses focus (so typing more letters ist not possible). Same while navigation with arrow keys. After pressing, the shown value gets updated once and the component loses focus.

Does anybody know this bug and maybe has a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I started a topic in jquery Mobile forum.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/bug-on-ie11-with-select-tag#14737000005934537
There I got the information: the behavior in IE is default.
In my option, it has to be a bug in Firefox then, because behavior ist different.

Anyway, if anybody else runs into the same problem:
This part of code causes the behavior. I just commented it out as I don't know any solution how to modify from outside at the moment.

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/forms/select.js#L142-L150
>
> ```
>    if ( !!options.nativeMenu) {
>        self._delay(function () {
>        self.select.blur();
>        });
>    }
> ```